# pod install -bash: pod: command not found

Tags: ios, cocoapods, pod-install

I installed `pod` some time ago. However, it's stopped working so I'm working through [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Creating-a-project-that-uses-CocoaPods) again.

However, I almost immediately run into a problem here:

```
pod install
-bash: pod: command not found
```

Any suggestions why this happened?

Answer (score 646, accepted):

OK, found the problem. I upgraded Ruby some time ago and blasted away a whole load of gems. Solution:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

For none-sudo use:

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
gem install cocoapods --user-install
```

Comment: if "$ sudo gem install cocoapods" does not work for you with error installing cocoapods: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2 then see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871329/error-installing-google-analytics-on-ios-app/38373354#38373354

Comment: Why sudo is needed here ? isn't it bad practice to install with sudo ?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to use *sudo*, see below https://stackoverflow.com/a/47333482/1158376

Comment: Has anyone else tried this and still gotten the same error as before running it? Still looking for a solution

Comment: Don't try this for M1. Else you need to suffer with un-installing and re-installing stuff with homebrew.

Answer (score 101):

This Step Is Proper Working.

**Pod Install**

[ 1 ] Open terminal and type:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Gem will get installed in Ruby inside the System library. Or try on 10.11 Mac OSX El Capitan, type:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

If there is an error "activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.xx", then install the latest active support first by typing in the terminal.

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
```

[ 2 ] After installation, there will be a lot of messages, read them and if no error found, it means cocoa pod installation is done. Next, you need to set up the cocoa pod master repo. Type in terminal:

```
pod setup
```

And wait it will download the master repo. The size is very big (370.0MB in Dec 2016). So it can be a while. You can track the download by opening Activity and go to the Network tab and search for git-remote-https. Alternatively, you can try adding verbose to the command like so:

```
pod setup --verbose
```

[ 3 ] Once done it will output "Setup Complete", and you can create your XCode project and save it.

[ 4 ] Then in a terminal cd to "your XCode project root directory" (where your .xcodeproj file resides) and type:

```
pod init
```

[ 5 ] Then open your project's podfile by typing in terminal:

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

[ 6 ] Your Podfile will get open in text mode. Initially, there will be some default commands in there. Here is where you add your project's dependencies. For example, in the podfile, type

```
/****** These are Third party pods names ******/
pod 'OpenSSL-Universal'
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
pod 'FTPopOverMenu'
pod 'TYMActivityIndicatorView'
pod 'SCSkypeActivityIndicatorView'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'UPStackMenu'
```

(this is For example of adding library to your project).

When you are done editing the podfile, save it and close XCode.

[ 7 ] Then install pods into your project by typing in terminal:

```
pod install
```

Depending on how many libraries you added to your podfile for your project, the time to complete this varies. Once completed, there will be a message that says

"Pod installation complete! There are X dependencies from the Podfile and X total pods installed."

Comment: `sudo gem uinstall cocoapods` then `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` did it for me

Comment: ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
 The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.3. Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.3` and then running the current command again
 activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.

Answer (score 99):

**Installing CocoaPods on OS X 10.11**

These instructions were tested on all betas and the final release of El Capitan.

**Custom GEM_HOME**

This is the solution when you are receiving above error

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/Software/ruby
$ export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby
$ gem install cocoapods
[...]
1 gem installed
$ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin
$ pod --version
0.38.2
```

Comment: Did not work for me. When I try "gem install cocopods" I get the error "activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2."

Answer (score 94):

For macOS:

```
brew install --cask cocoapods
```

Original answer (outdated):

```
brew install cocoapods
brew cask install cocoapods-app
```

Comment: `Error: Cask 'cocoapods-app' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

Comment: @rust brew cask search cocoapod? I don’t know.

Comment: `brew install --cask cocoapods` installs both the command line tool and the app.

Comment: @Dirk Thanks, that's the best solution for MacOS

Comment: `brew install --cask cocoapods` installs outdated version 1.5.2.

Comment: Maybe try to add this to your `~/.zshrc`: `alias pod="/opt/homebrew/bin/pod`

Comment: nothing worked for me, only this solution , thanks

Answer (score 55):

You have to restart Terminal after installing the gem. Or you can simply open a new tab Terminal to fix.

Comment: I did it but nothing had changed still it doesn't recognize my pod command I had installed cocoapods

Comment: Alternatively, you can call `. ~/.profile` which will setup your ruby env again.

Answer (score 41):

for M1mac people
first install cocoapods

```
brew install cocoapods
```

and if you are doing this for ios react-native

```
pod install
```

Comment: This worked for me!

I made a mistake by installing it using `gem` and it caused many linking issues

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, running Mountain Lion with Ruby 2 installed and used instead of system ruby.

Previously I added `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to my `~/.bash_profile` as a way to make sure stuff installed by `homebrew`, including Ruby 2, took precedence over system-installed binaries.

Anyway, in this case I noticed that cocoapods would install their 'pod' binary not in  `/usr/local/bin` but rather in `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/`

So to my .bash_profile I added `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/`
and now cocoapods is working like a charm.

Comment: I do not have this path file what should I do to follow?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should have a .bash_profile, you can't normally see it because of the . in front of the file name.

do first a plain `cd` in your terminal to go back to your home dir
followed b a `ls -a`, you should see all your files including a bash_profile

Comment: Thanks for tip. I soft linked the pod executable to /usr/local/bin, now everythings seem to be ok.

Comment: It is not ideal to hardcode the ruby version into the PATH. See this answer for how to do this generically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14138490/1531256

Answer (score 16):

1. Uninstall all instances of cocopods by this command

   ```
   $sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
   ```
2. `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`
3. `sudo chmod +rx /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: What does ``chmod +rx`` do?

Comment: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/bin directory.

But your process worked :)

Comment: Nice use of the `-n` option.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -V
```

and you must update gem to the newest release using this:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

if you want to enjoy the fast responce :)

Answer (score 12):

try:
    `rbenv global system`
and then
    `sudo gem install cocoapods`
    `pod setup`

Comment: This worked for me using `rbenv global system`. Typing simply `rbenv system` results in an error.

Comment: @MCSD Your should install [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) first.

Comment: Issue - rbenv: pod: command not found react-native -> above solution work for me

Answer (score 12):

**Sudo-less installation**

If you do not want to grant RubyGems admin privileges for this process, you can tell RubyGems to install into your user directory by passing either the --user-install flag to gem install or by configuring the RubyGems environment. The latter is in our opinion the best solution. To do this, create or edit the .profile file in your home directory and add or amend it to include these lines:

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Note that if you choose to use the --user-install option, you will still have to configure your .profile file to set the PATH or use the command prepended by the full path. You can find out where a gem is installed with gem which cocoapods. E.g.

```
$ gem install cocoapods --user-install
$ gem which cocoapods
/Users/eloy/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods.rb
$ /Users/eloy/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/pod install
```

Source: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

Answer (score 9):

In terminal it's better to run installation of the cocoa pods with "sudo". In other case I'm getting an error: "You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory."

So the solution is:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 6):

so I also had the same problem. This is probably happening because your computer has an older version of ruby. So you need to first update your ruby. Mine worked for ruby 2.6.3 version.I got this solution from sStackOverflow,

You need to first open terminal and put this code

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Then put this command

```
rvm install ruby-2.6
```

This would install the ruby for you if it hasn' t been installed.After this just update the ruby to the new version

```
rvm use ruby-2.6.3
```

After this just make ruby 2.6.3 your default

```
rvm --default use 2.6.3
```

This would possibly fix your issue. You can now put the command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

And the command

```
pod setup
```

I hope this was useful

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me. Make sure to not miss the last command (`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin`).

See [This](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692#issuecomment-113847612).

Answer (score 3):

**install cocoapods from https://cocoapods.org/app**

Commands & versions keep onchanging

so download tar and enjoy

Answer (score 2):

gterzian is on the right track, however, if you later update your version of ruby then you'll also have to update your .profile to point to the new versioned ruby directory. For instance, the current version of ruby is 2.0.0-p353 so you'd have to add /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/bin to your path instead.

A better solution is to add /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin to your PATH. /usr/local/opt/ruby is actually a symlink to the current version of ruby that homebrew automatically updates when you do an upgrade. That way you'll never need to update your PATH and always be pointing to the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

If you used homebrew to install ruby, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24045162/2532070) answer worked for me.

`brew unlink ruby && brew link ruby`

OSX 10.9.4

Answer (score 2):

it happens to me when I wrote

`gem install cocoapods`

instead of

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

if sudo command is not found also, write

`export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

before sudo command

Answer (score 2):

@Babul Prabhakar was right

IMPORTANT:
However,if you still get "pod: command not found" after using his solution, this command could solve your problem:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the **Ruby folder** from -Your Disk->Library->Ruby
Deleting this folder and use sudo gem install cocoapods command to solve my issue.
[image]

Comment: Not work around

Answer (score 2):

CocoaPods is built with Ruby and it will be installable with the default Ruby available on macOS. You can use a Ruby Version manager, however we recommend that you use the standard Ruby available on macOS unless you know what you're doing.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Resource: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

Answer (score 2):

It works for me:

```
brew update cocoapods
brew link cocoapods
```

Answer (score 2):

after

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

do

```
pod setup
```

then open new tab, check version of pod

```
pod --version
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using OS Catalina and used the solution of Babul Prabhakar.
But when I closed the terminal, pod still was unable.

So I put the exports:

```
$ export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby
$ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin
```

inside this file(put this command below inside the terminal):

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Then save the file, close the terminal and open it up again and type:

```
pod --version
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for Big Sur is posted on Redit by _fgmx

Go into Xcode 12 preferences Click locations Select Xcode 12 for Developer tools/command line tools Install cocoapods for Xcode 12: sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ever delete pod file from  */usr/local/bin* with terminal or any sudo,
you will need to install it to your bin folder, 
so use:

```
$ sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4`

then once cocoapods is successfully installed, try `pod` command again.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just run the following:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
Remove executables:
    pod, sandbox-pod

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  Y
```

and then

```
gem install cocoapods
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above, but this worked for me, and if you are using the latest Xcode this will also work for you:

> sudo gem install cocoapods

**Got Error:**

In Case `sudo gem install cocoapods` is not working for you, then you can follow these steps.

```
Error installing cocoapods:
The last version of drb (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 2.0.6.
drb requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 
 2.6.10.210.
```

Then Try installing it with `sudo gem install drb -v 2.0.6` and then running the current command again.

**Again Erro**
After running the above commands if you get the error again! saying that:

```
 Error installing cocoapods:
The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & 
RubyGems was 6.1.7.7.
```

Try installing it with `sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.7` and then running the current command again

> sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.7
>
> sudo gem install cocoapods

Now it will work for you. Happy Coding

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

We were using an incompatible version of Ruby inside of Terminal (Mac), but once we used RVM to switch to Ruby 2.1.2, Cocoapods came back.

Answer (score 0):

Install pod
sudo gem install cocoapods

Navigate inside platforms/ios
cd platforms/ios

Run pod install

Answer (score 0):

this [link](https://www.rubyonmac.dev/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension) help me a lot
it work now for me on catalina (patched for macbook pro 2011) with xcode 12.4.
may sure that you don't have another older version on your mac, for me having an old xcode 10.x in my download folder caused me many issue, so read verbose instruction in terminal, that help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

When I am installing cocoapod in terminal I got successfully install message but when I did init pod I got message that pod not found so I tried this.

```
export PATH="/Users/macOS_account_(username)/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:$PATH"
gem install cocoapods --user-install
```

Example:
My username is niyati in my macOS so I am useing like this.

```
export PATH="/Users/niyati/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:$PATH"
gem install cocoapods --user-install
```

It is usefull for me I hope it will usefull to all!!

Thank you!