# How to get the example of MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout working

Tags: ios, calendar, cocoapods

I downloaded the [MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout](https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout) and now I wanted to try out the example. If I open the *Example.xcodeproj* I only get errors e.g.

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found

I tried the tip from the [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installation-Troubleshooting) to change the project settings but it didn't worked. If I open the *Example.xcworkspace* I also only get errors.

Seems that the libraries are outdated. Is there a chance to get this project running?

**Edit:**

Now I tried to [install cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started). I created a *.profile* file in my home directory (where Documents, Desktop, Downloads resides in). I put this text into the file

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and then I run

```
gem install cocoapods --user-install
```

Because he didn't do something (was in the next line in terminal) I pressed *q*. Then he did something and I got the following warning

> WARNING:  You don't have /Users/my-user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin in your
>   PATH,       gem executables will not run.

Full output of terminal

```
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/my-user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
qSuccessfully installed i18n-0.7.0
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: minitest-5.6.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitest-5.6.1
Fetching: activesupport-4.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.1
Fetching: nap-0.8.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed nap-0.8.0
Fetching: fuzzy_match-2.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Fetching: cocoapods-core-0.37.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-core-0.37.1
Fetching: claide-0.8.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed claide-0.8.1
Fetching: colored-1.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed colored-1.2
Fetching: xcodeproj-0.24.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed xcodeproj-0.24.1
Fetching: cocoapods-downloader-0.9.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-downloader-0.9.0
Fetching: cocoapods-plugins-0.4.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-plugins-0.4.2
Fetching: cocoapods-try-0.4.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-try-0.4.4
Fetching: netrc-0.7.8.gem (100%)
Successfully installed netrc-0.7.8
Fetching: cocoapods-trunk-0.6.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-trunk-0.6.0
Fetching: molinillo-0.2.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed molinillo-0.2.3
Fetching: escape-0.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed escape-0.0.4
Fetching: cocoapods-0.37.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-0.37.1
Parsing documentation for i18n-0.7.0
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.7.0
Parsing documentation for thread_safe-0.3.5
Installing ri documentation for thread_safe-0.3.5
Parsing documentation for tzinfo-1.2.2
Installing ri documentation for tzinfo-1.2.2
Parsing documentation for minitest-5.6.1
Installing ri documentation for minitest-5.6.1
Parsing documentation for activesupport-4.2.1
unable to convert "\x84" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/active_support/values/unicode_tables.dat, skipping
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-4.2.1
Parsing documentation for nap-0.8.0
Installing ri documentation for nap-0.8.0
Parsing documentation for fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Installing ri documentation for fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-core-0.37.1
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-core-0.37.1
Parsing documentation for claide-0.8.1
Installing ri documentation for claide-0.8.1
Parsing documentation for colored-1.2
Installing ri documentation for colored-1.2
Parsing documentation for xcodeproj-0.24.1
Installing ri documentation for xcodeproj-0.24.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-downloader-0.9.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-downloader-0.9.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-plugins-0.4.2
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-plugins-0.4.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-try-0.4.4
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-try-0.4.4
Parsing documentation for netrc-0.7.8
Installing ri documentation for netrc-0.7.8
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-trunk-0.6.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-trunk-0.6.0
Parsing documentation for molinillo-0.2.3
Installing ri documentation for molinillo-0.2.3
Parsing documentation for escape-0.0.4
Installing ri documentation for escape-0.0.4
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.37.1
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-0.37.1
19 gems installed
```

Then I reopened the Xcode example, but I'm still getting the error that *RestKit.h* can't be found. What I'm doing wrong?

**Edit 2:**

Now I tried to use `pod install` in the example directory, but the [pod command was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19103214/426227). So I edited the `PATH` in *.profile* to this

```
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/ruby/2.0.0/bin:$PATH
```

Then I restarted terminal and run the command again

```
Analyzing dependencies
Creating shallow clone of spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`

Fetching podspec for `MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout` from `../`
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking 1.3.3 (was 1.3.3)
Installing CupertinoYankee 0.1.1 (was 0.1.1)
Installing ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer (0.5.0)
Using MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout (0.1.3)
Installing Masonry 0.4.0 (was 0.4.0)
Installing RKValueTransformers (1.0.1)
Installing RestKit 0.22.0 (was 0.22.0)
Installing SOCKit 1.1 (was 1.1)
Installing TransitionKit 2.0.0 (was 2.0.0)
Installing UIColor-HexString (1.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

Afterwards I opened *Example.xcworkspace* and got the error described by [Jakub Vano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4617259/jakub-vano). Then I unlocked and edited the `MASUtilities.h` according to [this link](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/issues/82) (commented enum and added the *static const*).

Now I got the project running!

Comment: When I reinstalled CocoaPods it compiled almost fine except for known issue with Masonry: https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/issues/82

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now I tried to install CocoaPods, but it still doesn't work (see my edited question). Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: After you installed CocoaPods utility, you need to run `pod install` in the Example directory, and open from `.xcworkspace` after that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works! Can you post your comments as an answer? Then I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to re-install CocoaPods for Example project:

- run `pod install` in the Example project directory
- run the project from the `.xcworkspace`

There will still be compile errors caused by known [issue](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/issues/82) with Masonry - as mentioned on linked issue, workaround is to replace problematic `enum` with

```
typedef float MASLayoutPriority;
static const MASLayoutPriority MASLayoutPriorityRequired = UILayoutPriorityRequired;
static const MASLayoutPriority MASLayoutPriorityDefaultHigh = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
static const MASLayoutPriority MASLayoutPriorityDefaultMedium = 500;
static const MASLayoutPriority MASLayoutPriorityDefaultLow = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow;
static const MASLayoutPriority MASLayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel = UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel;
```

Comment: Perhaps you can help out another time. Now I tried it again and I get `ndefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_RKLogCoreDataError", referenced from:
      ___33-[RKEntityByAttributeCache load:]_block_invoke in libRestKit.a(RKEntityByAttributeCache.o)
      ___43-[RKManagedObjectImporter finishImporting:]_block_invoke in libRestKit.a(RKManagedObjectImporter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`. Only found [this thread](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2876), but that didn't helped.

Comment: Please consider opening another question with new problem - that way questions wont get mixed up, and you might get solutions from other people as well..

Comment: Yes, sir! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704466/mscollectionviewcalendarlayout-example-undefined-symbols-for-architecture) you are.