# MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout example: undefined symbols for architecture

Tags: ios, calendar, cocoapods

I want that the example of [MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout](https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout) compiles and run.

Steps I've done:

- installed CocoaPods
- downloaded project
- run pod install in the Example project directory
- run the project from the .xcworkspace

Now I'm getting

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_RKLogCoreDataError", referenced from:
      ___33-[RKEntityByAttributeCache load:]_block_invoke in libRestKit.a(RKEntityByAttributeCache.o)
      ___43-[RKManagedObjectImporter finishImporting:]_block_invoke in libRestKit.a(RKManagedObjectImporter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried the tips from [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2876), but the version seem to be wrong.

How can I run this project?

Comment: What Xcode / Simulator / cocoapods version are you using? I wasn't able to reproduce this. However, it seems that problem is the static library `libRestKit.a`  not including `i386` architecture - this is weird, as standard name for library created by Cocoapods would be `libPods-RestKit.a`

Comment: Xcode: 6.4 / Simulator: iPhone 4S 8.4 / Cocoapod: 0.38.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, that `RestKit` version (`0.22.0`) specified in the `Podfile` is not compatible with `Cocoapods 0.38.x`. Switching to latest version `0.24.1` should fix this:

In Podfile:

```
pod 'RestKit', '0.24.1'
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but I used it with *RestKit/Network* and *RestKit/CoreData*. I thought I had your case too, but it seems not. Now it works! Thanks again!

Comment: Whenever i try to specify version 0.24.1 of RestKit in my podfile i get an error "Unable to satisfy the following requirements: `RestKit (= 0.24.1)` required by `Podfile`".  Does anyone know why?

Comment: @drvannostran98 you might have some other dependency (pod) which requires different version of `RestKit`. Try changing version to '>= 0.24.1'. If it does not help open another question with exact `Podfile` you are using.

Comment: i was able to resolve this by doing the following; sudo gem uninstall cocoa pods,
sudo gem install cocoapods,

pod repo remove master,
pod setup,
pod install