# Error installing google analytics on iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, cocoapods

I was trying to integrate google analytics into my project, and I was surprised that it requires cocoapods to install google analytics now.

I followed the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?hl=en

I called pod init on terminal, and then 
I've edited by podfile to

```html
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
end

target 'Unity-iPhone Tests' do

end
```

and I get the following error on terminal when I call pod install.

> Updating local specs repositories Analyzing dependencies [!] Unable to
>   find a specification for `Google/Analytics (~> 1.0.0)`
>
> [!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an
>   unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo
>   update --verbose`

It also did not generate the .xcworkspace file.

How can I fix this issue?

**Edit:**

I tried the answer by Steffen to setup the master repo again, and I get this error now.

> Analyzing dependencies [!] Unable to satisfy the following
>   requirements:
>
> - `Google/Analytics (~> 1.0.0)` required by `Podfile`

Although my podfile still contains 
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'

Comment: What version of CocoaPods are you using and what is the deployment target of your project?

Comment: Deployment target is 6.0 and cocoapod version is cocoapods-0.38.2

Comment: Can you try and put `platform :ios, '6.0'` at the top of your podfile and see if that changes the error message?

Comment: Hi Steffen, It looks like it doesn't change the error message.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas but I assume it would work if you simply just specify `pod 'Google/Analytics', '1.0.0'` if you just want it up and running for now.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem on **OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.5**

1. Open terminal command prompt
2. Path to your XCode project folder

   ```
   $ cd /path/to/xcode/myProject/
   ```
3. Create the Podfile using command

   ```
   $ pod init
   ```
4. Add the line `pod 'Google/Analytics'` to the generated Podfile

> ```
>      # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
>      # platform :ios, '8.0'
>      # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
>      # use_frameworks!
>
>      target 'myProject' do 
>      pod 'Google/Analytics'
>      end
> ```

5. Try to install the pod which fails

   ```
   $ pod install
   -bash: pod: command not found
   ```
6. Try to install cocoapods which also fails

   ```
   $ sudo gem install cocoapods 
   ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
   ```
7. You need to install activesupport which then lets you install cocoapods okay but then the pod install fails with a new bug

   ```
   $ sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
   $ sudo gem install cocoapods
   $ pod install
   [!] Unable to find a specification for 'Google/Analytics'
   ```
8. Perform these last steps and the pod install will finally succeed

   ```
   $ pod repo remove master
   $ pod setup
   $ pod install
   ```

**NB** Some of these command line actions take a long time to complete and Terminal gives you no indication that it is doing anything, it appears broken but is working quietly therefore needs patience.

So sad that we still have to resort command line in 2016

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your master repo is somehow corrupt. I would try the following:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated the question because it seems to give different error this time after I tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the project deployment target to 7.0 fixed the issue.