# bash: pod: command not found while running pod install

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm getting pod:command not found error when trying to run pod install for the google iOS SDK, in a swift/Xcode 7.2 project.   I've created the Podfile.  I have successfully installed cocoapods (.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods.rb) on Mac running OSX v10.11.3.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show your podfile ?

Comment: What do you get when you run `gem environment` in the terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pod install -bash: pod: command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202255/pod-install-bash-pod-command-not-found)

Comment: Found a resolution with a comment from neonichu, link: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692 ; it wasn't my pod file; installing cocoapods on OS version 10.11 was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it's working for me.

1) sudo mkdir -p $Home/Software/ruby

2) export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby

3) gem install cocoapods

4) export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin

5) pod --version

6) nano Podfile -> where you can edit your pod file. CtrlX and Press Y then press Enter.

7) pod install

it successfully installed without any error.