# Cannot install Cocoa pods in macOS sierra 10.12.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

When I trying to install the cocoapods rubygem (sudo gem install cocoapods),I got this error.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
  Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod
```

I tried specifying a new bin directory through `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` but that didn't solve my problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the value of your PATH variable please?

Comment: I don't know how to post the value of my PATH variable ,please tell me .

Comment: You have successfully installed cocoapods，your $PATH is not right. Try refer to this answer to setup $PATH http://stackoverflow.com/a/32989451/3940672

Comment: echo $PATH is what you need to execute to print it's contents

Comment: Awesome ! thank you very much! 
Rearranging the default path.move into the home directory 
'nano .bash_profile '
Create the .bash_profile file with a command line editor called nano
'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" '
Save the file in nano by clicking ‘control’ +’o’ and confirming the name of the file is .bash_profile by hitting return. And the ‘control’+’x’ to exit nano
So now when the Terminal is relaunched or a new window made and you check the the path by
'echo $PATH'
You will get a new path .
Then run 'pod setup'