# pod command is not recognized when running flutter project

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter, cocoapods, macos-mojave

I have tried every suggestion and solution in stack overflow and GitHub and yet I am not able to run pod install and I get pod : command not found , also my pod file is empty.

```
 Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds
  to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install:
  sudo gem install cocoapods

Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            6.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


 Xcode's output:
↳
    error: /Users/seyedaliaghamali/Documents/projects/my_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: 
could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-
Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')
    error: /Users/seyedaliaghamali/Documents/projects/my_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: 
could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-
Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')
    error: /Users/seyedaliaghamali/Documents/projects/my_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: 
could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-
Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')
    error: /Users/seyedaliaghamali/Documents/projects/my_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: 
could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-
Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')
    error: /Users/seyedaliaghamali/Documents/projects/my_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: 
could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-
Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')
    error: /Users/seyedaliaghamali/Documents/projects/my_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: 
could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-
Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')
    warning: Capabilities for Runner may not function correctly because its entitlements 
use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the build settings 
editor. (in target 'Runner')
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.
```

Comment: Take a looks at this question - it should solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904588/cocoapods-not-installing

Comment: then again I get the same error

Comment: what do you get when you run  pod --version?

Comment: pod : command not found

Comment: what do you get when you run -  sudo gem install cocoapods ?

Comment: You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.

Comment: Do you get the same if you run sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods ?

Comment: No that way I'm able to install the gem but again the pod command is not recognized , am I missing a step?

Comment: check if any answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202255/pod-install-bash-pod-command-not-found solves your problem. It's no flutter problem btw.

Comment: manyyyy thanks man! I forgot to export to the path

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by CocoaPods not being installed, therefore `pod install` can't be run. Simply install CocoaPods to solve this issue. Run either `sudo gem install cocoapods` or install it without sudo following this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47333482/2497859).