# How to generate ipa in react native using ubantu?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ipa

I just want to generate a ipa file.I have no real ios device.Please suggest a solution.

I tried adding
->react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios

->sudo react-native run-ios

But it is telling me to install pod ->Once I tried to run
-> npm install pod

But it didn't get installed.

I also tried command sudo gem install cocoapods  but I got error gem command not found.
sudo apt-get install rubygems
sudo apt  install ruby  # version 1:2.5.1
I tried to install ruby as well

Anyone come across this issue...plz suggest a solution..I have been struggling since morning for ipa.

Comment: These link could help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110496/how-to-build-ipa-application-for-react-native-ios

Comment: sudo react-native run-ios- I ran this command and this is the error I got>Did you run "pod install" in iOS directory? Could not get the simulator list from Xcode. Please open Xcode and try running project directly from there to resolve the remaining issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gem install cocoapods

cd ios

pod install
```

Comment: sudo gem install cocoapods ->I tried this but I get response gem: command not found              And pod install is not getting installed ->Command 'pod' not found.  Have come across this issue?

Comment: I think this issue will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202255/pod-install-bash-pod-command-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Helloo react developers..

Finally lots of R&D I get to know that if we are using react native cli...we can generate .ipa in MAC OS.

Other option is to use react-native expo....That helps in bilding .ipa file but u can't use simlator ...it supported only in mac os or ios.

If you guys know more..please share:)

I really struggle 2-3 days on ios .ipa and finally got this. I have shared the document reference too. It might me useful for u  guys :)

https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/c9bf40/how_to_generate_ipa_in_linux_using_react_native/
https://docs.expo.io/workflow/ios-simulator/

Happy coding :)