# Updating cocoapods to latest version doesn't do anything

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-mavericks, cocoapods

I'm currently using cocoapods 0.26.2 (output from `pod --version`). I want to update it to 0.29.0.

I ran `sudo gem update` which didn't appear to do anything with the cocoapods gem. So, following suggestions on cocoapods.org I tried:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

That did appear to install cocoapods 0.29.0. However, when I run `pod --version` it still tells me I'm on 0.26.2.

```
$ which pod
/usr/bin/pod
```

I tried renaming `/usr/bin/pod` to something else then trying the uninstall / reinstall again, but it doesn't put a pod binary in `/usr/bin`. It **DOES** however put a pod binary in `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin`. Do I really need to add that odd and version hard coded path to my `$PATH`?? Why did cocoapods previously install into `/usr/bin`?

My gem environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.1.9
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/michael/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/michael/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /opt/X11/bin
```

I'm running OS X 10.9.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, [this answer about ruby and homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14138490/368085) solved the problem. Had to add `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin` to my `$PATH`. Not sure how I ever had a version of the pod binary in `/usr/bin`, it's possible I used the OS X provided version of ruby to install the earlier version of cocoapods, not the version installed by homebrew.